# Maximal ideal in UFD, which is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

My question:

Let $R$ be a noetherian unique factorization domain, which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra (hence $R = \mathbb{Z}[a_1,...,a_n]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$) and contains at least one prime/irreducible element. Which further conditions do we need to be sure that there exists a prime/irreducible element $r \in R$ such that $R/rR$ is a field?

My ideas/attempts:

If $\dim{R}=1$, where $\mathrm{dim}$ denotes the Krull dimension, then any prime element $r$ has this property. On the other hand, it is well-known that $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$ does not have this property and that $\dim{\mathbb{Z}[X]} = 2$. Do there exist such rings $R$ with $\dim{R} \geq 2$, which also fulfil the property?

If we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$, then we can apply Krulls principal ideal theorem: Since $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra and an integral domain, we know that every maximal chain of prime ideals in $R$ has length $\dim{R}$. But the principal ideal theorem inplies that $pR$ contains only one prime ideal, namely $(0)$. As $rR$ is maximal, this immediately implies $\dim{R} = 1$. So in this case, the statement holds if and only if $R$ has Krull dimension $1$.

Comment: I'm not certain every dimension $1$ ring has a prime **element**. Definitely any prime **ideal** is maximal, but you've not asked for something on an ideal level. Are you meaning some prime ideal or do you really mean element?

Comment: Yes, I mean a prime (or irreducible) element. But your objection might be correct, let us assume that $R$ has such elements. I will edit it in my question.

Comment: I never heard about UFDs without prime elements (unless they are fields).

Comment: @user26857 I'm not certain they don't exist off the top of my head, but certainly that is an unstated assumption in the problem which should absolutely be proven or addressed.

Comment: They don't - a domain is a UFD if and only if every nonzero prime ideal contains a prime element (Kaplansky).